# Google map not rendering in razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, razor

I've removed float left from the mapCanvas css as suggested by Nava:

```
#mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    /*float: left;*/
}
```

I've also removed second reference to jQuery at the end of the view...

[image]

```css
#mapCanvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
}
#infoPanel {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#infoPanel div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@model PetBookMVC2.Models.LostAndFound @{ ViewBag.Title = "Registrar Mascota Extraviada"; }

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="alert alert-info" hidden="hidden">@ViewBag.Message</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "LostAndFounds", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal col-md-6">
  <h4>Ingrese los datos de su mascotita extraviada...</h4>
  <hr />@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdPet) @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdUser)


  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Ingrese una Título" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "Título de su anuncio de Mascota Extraviada", new { @class = "text-danger"
      })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateLost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateLost, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Ingrese fecha de extravio..." }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateLost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Latitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Latitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "latbox" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Latitude, "Debe ingresar la Latitud", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Longitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Longitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "lngbox" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Longitude, "Debe ingresar la Longitud", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Teléfono de Contacto" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "Ingrese un teléfono de contacto", new { @class = "text-danger"
      })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Teléfono de Contacto" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "Ingrese un teléfono de contacto", new { @class = "text-danger"
      })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Ingrese una referencia" } }) @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes, "Debe ingresar una referencia", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
      <input type="submit" value="Grabar" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </div>

  @Html.ActionLink("Regresar al Listado", "Index")

</div>

}

<div class="row">
  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Estado del Marcador</b>
    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Haga Click y arrastre el marcador</i>
    </div>
    <b>Posicion actual</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="lat"></div>
    <div id="lng"></div>
    <b>Dirección más cercana</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</div>

@section Scripts { @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { // will trigger when the document is ready
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    }); //Initialise any date pickers
    initialize();
  });


  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


  function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      latLng: pos
    }, function(responses) {
      if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
        updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
      } else {
        updateMarkerAddress('No se puede determinar la dirección de esta ubicación');
      }
    });
  }

  function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
    document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
  }

  function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
      latLng.lat(),
      latLng.lng()
    ].join(', ');

    document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = latLng.lng();

    //document.getElementById('latbox').innerHTML = latLng.lat();
    //document.getElementById('lngbox').innerHTML = latLng.lng();
  }

  function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
    document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
  }

  function initialize() {

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-12.0711893, -77.0698524);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
      zoom: 17,
      center: latLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        latLng = pos;
        map.setCenter(pos);

      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter()); // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    }


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      title: 'Por acá se perdió mi mascotita',
      map: map,
      draggable: true
    });

    // Update current position info.
    updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
    geocodePosition(latLng);


    // Add dragging event listeners.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
      updateMarkerAddress('Arrastrando...');
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
      updateMarkerStatus('Arrastrando...');
      updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
      updateMarkerStatus('Arrastre finalizado');
      geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
    });

  }

  // Onload handler to fire off the app.
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
}
```

HI, I've been trying to make this code work in my Mvc web but I can't find the reason why is not rendering. I have exact the same code in a new project and it works fine, but not in mine.

Here's my code... the only difference I found with the project that works is the
JavaScript version 1.10.2 versus 2.2.1 which I actually use. Even in this snippet the code works fine... I'm loosing my mind!

Comment: Could you include a screenshot showing the row where the map should render? I'm curious to see how the other div "infoPanel" is showing. I have a feeling that the float:left in the mapCanvas might be causing row to now have the correct height. Can you try removing float:left from #mapCanvas css definition?

Comment: Hi Nava, thanks for your prompt reply! I did what you suggested removing float left but nothing happen yet.

Answer (score 0):

You included the url to your site and I took a look. Seems you are getting a Javascript error when you try to create `google.maps.Map`.

This is where I would begin my investigation.

[image]

On a side note, you are including jQuery twice, but /Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js is returning a 404.

Comment: Hi Nava! I've removed the second reference to jQuery and also modified the Css class attribute of the div map, removing float: left; but the map doesn't render yet. I suspect that is something to do with the razor bundles and render sections (partials) because the same code works fine in a brand new project without partials.

Comment: Try running the site locally and keep your bundle. This will cause it to load the files individually. Basically, bundling does not optimize when you are running locally so you can better debug.

Comment: I've ran it locally as well but I got the same issue. I'm not able to debug the JavaScript part, though.